# How to create a summary report from a LibreOfficeCalc PivotTable

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

This is a question about the feasibility of solving a problem with LibreOffice/Calc.

I have a table of data of many years with basically the following columns:

```
date/time ( Y/M/D time )
quantity
```

Now, I want to make views of this table as follows:

```
VIEW-1:
quantity by weekday
 . Mon - Sum Qty
 . Tue - Sum Qty 
 .
 . Sun - Sum Qty
```

.

```
VIEW-2:
quantity by year/week
 . 2010 Wk 1 - Sum Qty
 . 2010 Wk 2 - Sum Qty
 . 
 . 2021 Wk 33 - Sum Qty
```

And many, many other views.

My question is as follows.

**Is it possible to create such views (reports) with the help of LibreOffice/Calc Pivot tables in a straightforward manner?**

If so, could you give a hint as to how to create maybe one of the above views (reports)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step-by-step to produce the two pivot tables in LibreOffice Calc 6.4.

Note the use of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
dates and week numbers with Monday being start of week; dates in early
January for ISO week 52 or 53 will be listed as week zero (`W00`) for
correct sort order within a year.

Create a data table in a named range by adding 3 columns to the
existing `Date` and `Qty` columns:

- insert/edit a header row with these column texts:
  `Date`, `Qty`, `Year`, `WeekISO`, `Weekday`
- in the row below the header insert following formulas, editing `A2` to
  match the cell of the first `Date` and `;` to match the list separator
  of your locale
- in the `Year` column insert `=YEAR(A2)`
- in the `WeekISO` column insert `=IF(AND(1=MONTH(A2);52<=WEEKNUM(A2;21));"W00";TEXT(WEEKNUM(A2;21);"W0#"))`
- in the `Weekday` column insert `=WEEKDAY(A2;2)` and (in Format > Cells …)
  give the cell format code `NN` for locale's abbreviated weekday name
- copy the formulas to all data rows
- select (highlight) the table area incl. header row
- in Sheet > Named Ranges… > Define..., enter range name `dataset1`, Add

Create a pivot table for VIEW-1 quantity by weekday:

- Data > Pivot Table > Insert or Edit ..., named range `dataset1`, OK
- from `Available Fields` drag `Weekday` and drop on `Row Fields`
- from `Available Fields` drag `Qty` and drop on `Data Fields`
- `Column Fields` should contain `Data`
- accept/edit Options + Source and Destination (defaults are okay), OK
- create a custom sort list: select the 7 daynames in the pivot table,
  in Tools > Options > … Calc > Sort Lists: Copy from …, edit list, OK
- sort the pivot table: click arrow at `Weekday` header, Custom Sort,
  choose a list

Create a pivot table for VIEW-2 quantity by year/week:

- as for VIEW-1 except

  - set `Row Fields` to: `Year` and `WeekISO`
  - set `Data Fields` to: `Qty`
  - no custom sort
- in the pivot table: swop the pivot fields by clicking header in column B

---

As you suggest a recurring need to create pivot tables you may be
interested in the LibreOffice Basic code to repeat the steps
programmatically; assumes the data table is defined in the named range
`dataset1`, and the pivot tables are not.
[Link](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/module-ix.html)
to OOo API docs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PivotDemo

    Const rawRgName = "dataset1"        '' defined in Calc sheet
    Const pivot1Name = "qtyByWeekday"
    Const pivot2Name = "qtyByYearWeekISO"
    Const pivot1Sheet = pivot1Name & "_auto_pivot"
    Const pivot2Sheet = pivot2Name & "_auto_pivot"
    Const grandTotalLabel = "Grand total"
    Const fieldNameQty = "Qty"
    Const fieldNameWeekday = "Weekday"
    Const fieldNameWeekISO = "WeekISO"
    Const fieldNameYear = "Year"

    '' initialize
 
    Dim cdoc : cdoc = ThisComponent
    Dim scrRaw      '' com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRange
    scrRaw = cdoc.NamedRanges.getByName(rawRgName).getReferredCells()
    Dim dptColl     '' com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotTables
    dptColl = scrRaw.getSpreadsheet().getDataPilotTables()
    Dim dptDesc     '' com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotDescriptor
    Dim dpFields    '' com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFields
    Dim dpfsi       As New com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldSortInfo
    With dpfsi
        .Field = "__replace_with_field_name__"
        .IsAscending = True
        .Mode = com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldSortMode.NAME
    End With
    Dim pivotAddr   As New com.sun.star.table.CellAddress
    Dim sheetIndex  As Integer


    '' create pivot table #1 in a new Calc sheet

    dptDesc = dptColl.createDataPilotDescriptor()
    dptDesc.setSourceRange(scrRaw.getRangeAddress())
    dptDesc.ShowFilterButton = False

    dpFields = dptDesc.getDataPilotFields()
    dpfsi.Field = fieldNameWeekday
    With dpFields.getByName(fieldNameWeekday)
        .Orientation = com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldOrientation.ROW
        .Function = com.sun.star.sheet.GeneralFunction.SUM
        .SortInfo = dpfsi
        .HasSortInfo = True
    End With
    With dpFields.getByName(fieldNameQty)
        .Orientation = com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldOrientation.DATA
        .Function = com.sun.star.sheet.GeneralFunction.SUM
    End With

    sheetIndex = cdoc.Sheets.getCount()
    cdoc.Sheets.insertNewByName(pivot1Sheet, sheetIndex)
    With pivotAddr : .Sheet=sheetIndex : .Column=0 : .Row=0 : End With
    dptColl.insertNewByName(pivot1Name, pivotAddr, dptDesc)


    '' create pivot table #2 in a new Calc sheet

    dptDesc = dptColl.createDataPilotDescriptor()
    dptDesc.setSourceRange(scrRaw.getRangeAddress())
    dptDesc.ShowFilterButton = False
    dptDesc.GrandTotalName = grandTotalLabel
    dptDesc.RowGrand = True
    dptDesc.ColumnGrand = True

    dpFields = dptDesc.getDataPilotFields()
    dpfsi.Field = fieldNameYear
    With dpFields.getByName(fieldNameYear)
        .Orientation = com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldOrientation.ROW
        .Function = com.sun.star.sheet.GeneralFunction.NONE '' .SUM for subtotals
        .SortInfo = dpfsi
        .HasSortInfo = True
    End With
    dpfsi.Field = fieldNameWeekISO
    With dpFields.getByName(fieldNameWeekISO)
        .Orientation = com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldOrientation.ROW
        .Function = com.sun.star.sheet.GeneralFunction.NONE '' .SUM for subtotals
        .SortInfo = dpfsi
        .HasSortInfo = True
    End With
    With dpFields.getByName(fieldNameQty)
        .Orientation = com.sun.star.sheet.DataPilotFieldOrientation.DATA
        .Function = com.sun.star.sheet.GeneralFunction.SUM
    End With

    sheetIndex = cdoc.Sheets.getCount()
    cdoc.Sheets.insertNewByName(pivot2Sheet, sheetIndex)
    With pivotAddr : .Sheet=sheetIndex : .Column=0 : .Row=0 : End With
    dptColl.insertNewByName(pivot2Name, pivotAddr, dptDesc)

End Sub


    '' refresh pivot:  dptColl.getByName(pivot1Name).refresh()
    '' remove pivot:   dptColl.removeByName(pivot1Name)
    '' activate sheet: ThisComponent.CurrentController.setActiveSheet(_
    ''                 dptColl.getByName(pivot1Name).getOutputRange().Sheet )
    '' remove sheet:   ThisComponent.Sheets.removeByName(pivot1Sheet)
```